# How to group years in decades in sqlite3 in jupyter notebook?

Tags: sql, sqlite, jupyter

I'm suppose to Find the decade D with the largest number of films and the total number of films in D. A decade is a sequence of 10 consecutive years. For example, say in your database you have movie information starting from 1965. Then the first decade is 1965, 1966, ..., 1974; the second one is 1967, 1968, ..., 1976 and so on.

I'm suppose to implement this in jupyter note book where I imorpted sqlite3
I wrote the following code for it.

```
Select count(*) as total_films,concat(decade,'-',decade+9)
FROM (Select floor(YEAR('year')/10)*10 as decade FROM movie) t
GROUP BY decade
Order BY total_films desc;
```

However, the notebook threw error like "no such function: floor" and "no such function: Year" and no such function: concat"

Therefore, after going through sqlite documentation I changed code to

```
Select count(*) as total_films,decade||'-'||decade+9
FROM (Select cast(strftime('%Y',year)/10 as int)*10 as decade FROM movie) t
GROUP BY decade
Order BY total_films desc;
```

However, I got an incorrect output :

```
   count(*)  decade||'-'||decade+9

0       117                    NaN

1      3358                 -461.0
```

Would appreciate insights on why this is happening.

Updating question after going through comments by c.Perkins

1) I began, checking the type of year column

using the query `PRAGMA table_info(movie)`

Got the following result

```
   cid       name     type  notnull dflt_value  pk
0    0      index  INTEGER        0       None   0
1    1        MID     TEXT        0       None   0
2    2      title     TEXT        0       None   0
3    3       year     TEXT        0       None   0
4    4     rating     REAL        0       None   0
5    5  num_votes  INTEGER        0       None   0
```

Since the year column is of the type text I changed to int using the cast function and check for nulls or NaN `SELECT CAST(year as int) as yr FROM MOVIE WHERE yr is null`

I didn't get any results, therefore it appears there are no nulls. However, on using the query `SELECT CAST(year as int) as yr FROM MOVIE order by yr asc` I see a lot of zeros in the year column

```
        yr
0        0
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        0
-
-
-
-
3445  2018
3446  2018
3447  2018
3448  2018
3449  2018
3450  2018
```

From the above we see that the year is given as it is and in another stamp, therefore using strftime('%Y', year) did not yield result as mentioned in the comment.

Therefore, keeping all the above in mind, I changed the inner query to

```
SELECT (CAST( (year/10) as int) *10) as decade FROM MOVIE WHERE decade!=0 order by decade asc
```

Output for the above query :

```
     decade
0       1930
1       1930
2       1930
3       1930
4       1930
5       1930
6       1940
7       1940
8       1940
-
-
-
3353    2010
3354    2010
3355    2010
3356    2010
3357    2010
```

Finally, placing this inner query, in the first query I wrote above

```
Select count(*) as total_films,decade||'-'||decade+9 as period
FROM (SELECT (CAST( (year/10) as int) *10) as decade FROM MOVIE WHERE decade!=0 order by decade asc)
GROUP BY decade
```

Output :

```
    total_films  period
0            6    1939
1           12    1949
2           71    1959
3          145    1969
4          254    1979
5          342    1989
6          551    1999
7          959    2009
8         1018    2019
```

As far as I can see the only issue is with period column where instead of showing 1930-1939 it is only showing 1939 and so on, if is using || is not right, is there anythother function that could be used ? because concat is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to pare down the information to necessary tables and data.  The key question is mainly about getting decades from a single column.  Further, the only source table in the code is `movie`.  All the other table schema is unnecessary and a distraction for this question.  **Update the question to focus on the table movie only.  Show sample rows from the table `movie`.** Otherwise we can only guess what the data looks like, since the final data you shared is aggregate data with details hidden.  Does it have nulls?  Is the column `year` a full date or only the year?  Etc.

Comment: Also, it is good debugging practice to **always** look at results of inner queries when the outer query results are incorrect.  It is especially useful for those helping you to see the data.  Include naked column data (outside an expression) so that you can determine if the expressions are correct or not.  In other words, show the results of a query like this: `SELECT year, cast(strftime('%Y',year)/10 as int)*10 AS decade FROM movie`

Comment: I've updated the question as per your suggestions, please let me know in case I've missout on anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are making too many assumptions about what operators and functions do, perhaps because they behave differently in other database or languages.  For instance, CAST( as Int) does not return null for non-inter string values, rather it returns 0.  If you want to check for null, then just check it directly:  `SELECT *  FROM MOVIE WHERE year is null`.  If needed, check for other non-integer with something like `WHERE Cast(year as int) = 0 AND year != '0'`.

Comment: Why cast **after** already treating the column as numeric?  For the expression `CAST( (year/10) as int)`, sqlite will already have attempted a cast of `year` to a numeric value so that it can divide it by 10.  If it was numeric it would already have done the cast.  If it was not numeric, it would have returned 0 and so the cast would still be unnecessary.  Although in this case I don't see any significant change in results, you need to be careful about the order of operations and whether they make sense or not.  If you insist on casting then it should be 'CAST(year as int) /10`

Comment: I already gave you the answer for the concatenation.  It has highest precedence, so it is doing the concatenation **before** the `+9`.  But because you are adding a string to a numeric value 9, sqlite is doing an automatic cast to integer.  In doing so it essentially ignores excess characters:  The string `'1930-1930'` is being converted to just `1930` integer value and then adding 9 to get `1939`.  **If you don't understand precedence or how to fix it, then I suggest reading up on it.  It is fundamental to programming properly.**

Comment: BTW, still too much information.  You really should delete the image with table information since all of that irrelevant to the question.  Don't make others who you are asking for help weed out unneeded information and make them scroll just to get to the heart of the issue.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, I'll make sure not to sure uncessary info in future :).

I've used cast (as int), because I thought it would round off (year/10)*10, i.e if year =1932, then year/10= 193.2, i thought if I do cast(year/10 as int ), it would drop the .2 and then multiply the 10, make it part of the decade 1930. Does sqlite directly cast as int ? 

Also, thank you exaplining about precedence, I was able to solve it by using decade||'-'||(decade+9), is that the right of doing it ? or did I get right answer by following the wrong method?

Once agains,thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Parenthesis are precisely the answer for controlling order of operations.  I could have just shared that, but some concepts are too important / extensive to just give a quick answer, rather should be studied separately.  I'm glad you found the solution.  I re-interpreted the purpose of the cast based on your edited comments, so I thought it was meant to convert the string column.  If it was meant to drop the decimal values, then it is a valid technique... and it doesn't hurt, but in this case also unnecessary.  See the part of my answer about *integer division*.

Comment: In summary, it seems the overall problem was a series of misunderstandings of sqlite's operators, conversions, precedence, types, etc.  In the future it can be worth separately researching and testing each expression separately.  Try edge values like 0 (zero), nulls, empty strings, etc.  Output and inspect each term of an expression separately to see what is being returned.  Some modern languages seem to encourage ignoring these details as though they don't matter or that the language will always do conversions correctly, but it's worth learning and testing details of the language (even SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Pending updates to the question as requested in comments, here are a few immediate points that might help solve the problem without having all details:

- Does the `movie.year` column contain null values?  Likewise non-numeric or non-date values?  the `NaN` (Not A Number) result likely indicates a null/invalid data in the source.  (Technically there is no such NaN value in SQLite, so I'm assuming that the question data is copied form some other data grid or processed output.)
- What type of data is in the column `movie.year`?  Does it contain full ISO-8601 date strings or a Julian-date numeric value?  Or does it only contain the year (as the column name implies)?  If it only contains the year (as a string or integer), then the function call like `strftime('%Y', year)` will NOT return what you expect and is unnecessary.  Just refer to the column directly.

  - I suspect this is where the `-461.0` is coming from.
- The operator `/` is an "integer division" operator if both operands are integers.  A valid isolated year value will be an integer and the literal 10 is of course an integer, so **integer division will automatically drop any decimal part and returns only the integer part of the division** without having to explicitly cast to integer.
- According to [sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), the concatenation operator `||` has *highest precedence*.  That means in the expression `decade||'-'||decade+9`, the concatenation is applied first so that one possible intermediate would be `'1930-1930'+9`.  (Technically I would consider this result undefined since the string value does not contain a basic data type.  In practices on my system, the string is apparently interpreted as 1930 and the overall result is the integer value 1939.  Either way you will get unexpected bogus results rather than the desired string.)